The task.wait script keeps stopping my entire script
I wrote this script:
local mob = require(script.mob)
local map = workspace["level 0"]
local wave = 1
local spawntime = 1

if wave == 1 then
task.wait(1)
mob.Spawn("wretch", map)

end

It is supposed to spawn in a monster after one second, but instead of it waiting one second, it just stops the entire script and I can't figure it out. I have tried to get it to work by doing different things like to doing "wait(1)" instead or making it delay longer, but every time it won't work.
So, I need it to spawn in my monster which will be heading to your base since this is a td game after 1 second.

Could you share your Mob ModuleScript? If there's an issue in there, that could stop your script from ever getting to the task.wait() call.

local serverstorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local spawner = workspace["entity spawn"]
local mob = {}
function mob.Spawn(name, map)
local mobexsists = serverstorage.mobs:FindFirstChild(name)
if mobexsists then
local newmob = mobexsists:Clone()
newmob.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = spawner.CFrame
newmob.Parent = workspace
else
warn("mob isnt here")
end
end
return mob

If you remove thetask.wait call, does your code work normally?

yeah it does work
